# Как соединить реккурентные слои с одномерной свёрткой и полносвязными слоями

Tags: python, keras

Пыталась создать архитектуру, Но выдает ошибку, как учесть размерность между слоями?

```
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 8, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d4ca4b2095b5> in <module>()
      2 model.add(Embedding(max_words, 8, input_length=maxlen))
      3 model.add(LSTM(32))
----> 4 model.add(Conv1D(128, 3))
      5 model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    194                          ', found ndim=' + str(ndim) +
    195                          '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 196                          str(x.shape.as_list()))
    197     # Check dtype.
    198     if spec.dtype is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 32]
```

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5222

Comment: model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 8, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))